# Cancel key down event in Microsoft Edge

Tags: keyevent, keycode, microsoft-edge

How can I cancel a keydown event **in Microsoft Edge?**

I'm using next code for the key event to be canceled.

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

But in Microsoft Edge, this code does not apply.

I would like to cancel the event due to the **keycode 229.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me in EdgeHTML 13.10586:

```
<input id="test" type="text" />
<script async type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 191) event.returnValue = false;
    });
</script>
```

The 229 *keyCode* means that an Input Method Editor is processing key input. Can you provide us more context?